# What to do when listview.builder does not fit screen width in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The following is what is returned from a Flutter widget:

```
return Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                      SizedBox(
                          height: 250,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: annualFinancialReportList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              FinancialReport annualReport =
                                  annualFinancialReportList[index];

                              return Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: [
                                  const SizedBox(width: 3),
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Start Date",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .headline5,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                        child: Text(
                                          annualReport.startDate ?? "N/A",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .headline3,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                        child: Text(
                                          "End Date",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .headline5,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                        child: Text(
                                          annualReport.endDate ?? "N/A",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .headline3,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Filing Date",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .headline5,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                        child: Text(
                                          annualReport.filingDate ?? "N/A",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .headline3,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Filing Date",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .headline5,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                        child: Text(
                                          annualReport.filingDate ?? "N/A",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .headline3,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Filing Date",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .headline5,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                        child: Text(
                                          annualReport.filingDate ?? "N/A",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .headline3,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                ],
              ),
            );
```

The list appears on the screen within the specified **height** by the **SizedBox**. The listview is vertically scrollable by default. However, the content in each Row widget in the listview does not fit the screen width. Wrapping it with a SingleChildScrollView widget is not an option because it makes each row scrollable separately. Since the content is fairly large (in horizontal axis), I want the user to be able to scroll the screen in the horizontal axis as well.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the [`InteractiveViewer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) ?

Comment: This was the widget I was trying to remember. But I could not make it work.. If you could provide an example, it would really be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try nesting ListView.builder within a ListView that scrolls horizontally? Something like -

```
Container(
  height: height,
  width: width,

  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

    child: Container(
      height: height,
      width: width,

      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection : Axis.vertical
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Reduce width of 2nd container by 25 or wrap container with expanded

Comment: @edn check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72146441/16714498

Comment: This approach seems to be working if I specifically set height and width. But it is difficult to set a constant width because I want it to take as much space as needed based on the horizontal length of each item in each row. For instance, setting it to double.infinity or MediaQuery.of(context).size.width throws errors. Is there a way to dynamically set the width in the inner container above?